# Google Map not showing up in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I recently been updating my app and now my google maps is not showing up. It just shows up blank with the plus and minus buttons and nothing else.

My map fragment is:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class BreweryTappedMap extends Fragment {

    public BreweryTappedMap(){}

    String beerId = "";
    GoogleMap mMap;
    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    String userID;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_brewmap, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (map == null) {
            map = fragment.getMap();
            String url = "myMap";

            new GetVisitedBreweries(getActivity(), map).execute(url);        }
    }
}
```

The xml layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- Permission to write to external storage -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.HelloWidget" android:label="Beer of the Day">
            <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />

        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.SearchWidget" android:label="Search ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/search_widget" />

        </receiver>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.LogIn">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.Register" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.MainDraw" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.MainDrawer2" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="myKey"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myMapsKey"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Is your android:value="myMapsKey" still valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same issue, this is because of API key. By default I have used `debug.keystore` to generate the `SHA-1 key` and I got he API key from Google I have used it on developing time. Once the app is signed then the map wont work, so you have to  Generate SHA-1 key using same `keystore` file used for Signing the app.

Comment: is this a recent change?

Comment: Check so my issue was that in my developers console for APIs They key did not match the new package name of my app. I rebuilt my app with a new package name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need this in your manifest application tag to enable Google play service :

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Heres how to add it as a lib :

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

For me adding this worked in my /app/gradle dependencies :

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'

Comment: Have you added the Google Play Services lib to your project ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get `@integer/google_play_services_version` it usually means you have not added the Google Play services library to your project.

Comment: I added it in my gradle like this, is this wrong:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/66f77185b56eb815bc1e

Comment: That look ok as long as you added version 6.5.87 and not 3.1.36 like it says in the gist. Did you hit the  Sync Project with Gradle Files button in the toolbar ? I find it better to follow the instructions from Android Developers (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build using a certificate. Until you do so, google will not "waste" its map resources on your app :).

This [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) should help you.

Did you copy the needed libs in the `libs` folder ?